# MySQL 8 split string by comma and convert it into JSON ARRAY

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have the following string: `"a,b,c,d"` and I want to convert it into a json array, something like this `["a","b","c","d"]` is there any MySQL 8 function that can achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  CAST( 
    CONCAT('["', REPLACE('a,b,c,d', ',', '","'), '"]')
    AS JSON
  );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=517f34e60edf4f6665c74dac4814d5bb).

Answer (score -4):

```
select json_array("a,b,c,d");
+-----------------------+
| json_array("a,b,c,d") |
+-----------------------+
| ["a,b,c,d"]           |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: you've create an array with one entry